# Unexpected output, but code is not wrong

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to compile this on CodeBlocks (version 13.12). Somehow, the pointer is incremented before it is called by toupper()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(void)
{
 char str[80] = "the only way";
 char *p;

 p = str;

 while(*p){
    *p++ = toupper(*p);
 }

 printf(str);
 return 0;
}
```

This leads to the output "HE ONLY WAY" where as I am looking for the output "THE ONLY WAY". I tried it on my computer where it gives the wrong output. However, when I tried this code on a friends computer the code ran fine, giving the output "THE ONLY WAY".
My question is why does my output differ?
P.s If I replace

> *p++ = toupper(*p);

with

> > *p++ = toupper( *(p-1));

I get the desired output of "THE ONLY WAY".

Comment: 'Unexpected output, but code is not wrong' This title is a contradiction. Clearly, if the output is unexpected, then the code is likely incorrect. A much more helpful title will describe what the *actual problem* is.

Comment: Sorry, will keep that in mind in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is causing *undefined behaviour*. It is not valid to refer to a pointer more than once in the same statement if you are using the pre- or post- increment/decrement operators.

Change your code to:

```
*p = toupper(*p);
p++;
```

This will ensure that the pointer `p` is changed only *after* you have used it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3 .. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand
>   is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right
>   operands. **The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced**.

So your program has undefined behaviour.

For example MS VS 2014 outputs as you expected

```
THE ONLY WAY
```